# What is this covered bay on the side of my laptop?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

I bought a Toshiba Satellite c50-b-14d and there's this thing on the side:

[image]

What is that outline? I know it's not a optical disc drive even though it's displayed in the BIOS.

Comment: A giant pile of laundry?

Comment: No, the laptop.

Comment: I took this on my ipad

Comment: Toshiba have probably just reused a chassis that has a slot for an optical drive and to save money they didn't install one.

Comment: 1) "I know it's not a optical disc drive even though it's displayed in the BIOS." uhm, so an optical drive is visible in the BIOS or did we miss a "not" ?
2) Could be a place for an optional optical drive, or a bay for an optional second HDD/SDD.  What does the manual mention?

Comment: Enhancements to your question: 
- Are there nuts/ bolts / screws holding it? Can they be unscrewed? 
- If you put a little pressure, do the seams give; indicating 2 pieces, or are they "joined" as one? 
- Does it appear - glued, single piece or screwed on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, that looks like a modular drive bay. Some chassis have the option to add devices like drives and adapters.

[image]

Some even have the option for additional storage drives.

[image]

Note: according to the [specs for your system](http://www.toshiba.co.uk/laptops/satellite/c50-b/satellite-c50-b-14d/tab/accessories/), it appears it did not come with an optical drive. So, what you see is likely a "plug" for aesthetics.